# find worksheet function working for only left

Tags: excel, vba

have a combobox where it'll either populate `name - ID` or   `ID - name`. I can determine that based on an option button that is pressed or isn't pressed. I then want to split up that combo box value into two separate columns so I can place name in column E, id in column F.

```
    If optEmployeeName.Value = True Then
        .Cells(5).Value = Left(cmbEmployee, (Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" - ", cmbEmployee, 1) - 1))
        .Cells(6).Value = Right(cmbEmployee, (Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" - ", cmbEmployee, 1) - 1))
    ElseIf optEmployeeID.Value = True Then
        .Cells(5).Value = Right(cmbEmployee, (Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" - ", cmbEmployee, 1) - 1))
        .Cells(6).Value = Left(cmbEmployee, (Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" - ", cmbEmployee, 1) - 1))
    End If
```

it works for the name in column E, but when I try `Right(...` it just spits out the whole value, any ideas how to fix this?

Solution minus trim:

```
    Dim lString As String, lArray() As String
    lString = cmbEmployee.Value
    lArray = Split(lString, " - ")
    If optEmployeeName.Value = True Then
        .Cells(5).Value = lArray(0)
        .Cells(6).Value = lArray(1)
    ElseIf optEmployeeID.Value = True Then
        .Cells(5).Value = lArray(1)
        .Cells(6).Value = lArray(0)
    End If
```

Comment: Probably easier to use `Split` and `Trim`.

Comment: @BigBen ok so I updated my post with a solution, would I just change it to `trim(lArray(0)` if I wanted to omit extra spaces? Also is there a more elegant way to do this? or is this the shortest block of code I can get?

Comment: If you wanted to omit all extra space, you could use the replace function. Also the `.Value` are superfluous, so a quick change would be `lArray = Split(Replace(lString," ",""),"-")` and `.Cells(5) = lArray(0)` etc

Comment: Also, I wouldn't assign lString for a single use, but just use cmbEmployee directly in the function so you wouldn't need to Dim lString. Therefore `lArray = Split(Replace(cmbEmployee," ",""),"-")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question; find returns the position where it found the character. In order for `Right` to work correctly you need to subtract the position from the length of the entire string which is why it isn't working.

As a solution and working on some assumptions that there is always a name and ID and that the optEmployeeName and Not(optEmployeeID) would always be the same...

```
Dim lArray() As String: lArray = Split(Replace(cmbEmployee," ",""),"-") 
.Cells(5) = IIf(optEmployeeName = True, lArray(0), lArray(1))
.Cells(6) = IIf(optEmployeeName = True, lArray(1), lArray(0))
```

> If you just want to trim leading and/or ending space then the following alternative should work:

```
Dim lArray() As String: lArray = Split(cmbEmployee,"-") 
.Cells(5) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(IIf(optEmployeeName = True, lArray(0), lArray(1)))
.Cells(6) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(IIf(optEmployeeName = True, lArray(1), lArray(0)))
```